Slow response in application 75% of the time
have an application that run slow, but not always, maybe 75% of the time. When its slow its lots of Sp_cursorfetch lines in profiler. Its not my application so its not possible to change any query. If i copy the database and application to my computer its not slow att all. Its only when the database and application are on different serveres. Its random what i do (what query) in the application that have slow response. Can do the samething 4-5 times and one of them is fast and its the exact same query that is created in profiler.
The behavior is the same any time of day. So is there any network setting that could do this?
Microsoft SQL server.
The application use ODBC

figure it out
You should look at server level wait stats on both the slow and fast servers, in total and when the workload is running.
If the difference is network-related waits, then it's likely all the cursor round trips to fetch rows (usually a single row at a time) that is the difference between local and separate installs.
You can use my stored procedure sp_PressureDetector to look into wait stats (among other things). You may also find sp_WhoIsActive useful in troubleshooting queries currently executing.

The problem was on the Hyper-V server that hosts this servers. It was network related.
